# How effectively to search through MSE resources

Tags: discussion, search

I'm on MSE one year but I'm still don't know how to effectively  search through MSE resources to get required information. The search machine is very inaccurate and rarely gives high quality response. It seems that much better method is to ask the question only in order to receive valuable references in the section *similar question*.
So they are existing but it's somehow hard to find them.
Even google seems to be better at pointing towards valuable MSE posts than search engine of MSE.
Are there any tips how to use effectively search engine of MSE ?

Comment: Some of the links collected [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/links-about-searching-for-posts-on-mse) might be useful. There is even a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/46148) devoted - to some extent - to searching.

Comment: Thank you Martin, .. can we use also some special commands for searching instead of  writing only a phrase ?

Comment: I've found that https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching is especially useful ..

Comment: For searching using Latex https://approach0.xyz/search/

Comment: Interesting tool, thank you Zaid..

Comment: I almost never use the Search Q&A box unless I'm looking for a single specific post, and even then it's not my first choice.  Generally I use google.  But when looking for a specific post I'll type my question into the Ask Question feature since it generally seems better at finding what I'm looking for than the Search Q&A box.